# OnGet Route Data not Binding to Property Not Binding IE 11

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have an OnGet Method in Razor Pages which has a Page Route of /somepage/somewhere/{id}, on issuing a request to the browser works as expected. 'id' holds the same values as 'intId'. When making a XMLHttpRequest post to an alternate page using Internet Explorer 11 (don't get me started on IE11), which redirects to this page (with return RedirectToPage('/somepage/somewhere', new { id = "xyz" }), the method is hit which tells me the routing is working as expected (Page without Id throws a 404), however 'id' is null, intId is as expected and values contains the 'id' and the 'page'. This works fine in Chrome to add a level of complexity to it.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string id)
 {
         var intId = _accessor.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("id")?.ToString();
    
         var values = _accessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values;
         
         // Lots Omitted
         
         return Page();
 }
```

Anyone have any thoughts on what could be going on here or why a property would not be bound with routedata as intended?

Comment: How did you post id in XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Yup and this works perfectly I chrome so has to be something obscure with IE